# Subview not closing causing Memory Leak Phonegap

Tags: memory-leaks, cordova, childviewcontroller

I am having issues not being able to close CDVViewController when calling this custom refresh, it stays loaded in the background and loads a new one causing memory leaks/high memory usage. I have tried to use both release and removeFromSuperview for the webView, subview, CDVViewController, ChildViewController but none of them work. I am running a Tab Bar Controller via Storyboard, (another reason why I have to call CDVViewController as a subview) and when I use the web inspector via safari I can see the pages building up on that tab, and when I refresh on another tab (not using CDVViewController/phonegap) it works fine. Any help is much appreciated.

So here is my .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <ifaddrs.h>
#import <arpa/inet.h>
#import <Cordova/CDVViewController.h>


@interface ThirdViewController : CDVViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
{
  IBOutlet CDVViewController *webView;
  IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityind;
}
- (IBAction)Refresh:(id)sender;


@end
```

And my .m

```
@interface ThirdViewController ()
@end
@implementation ThirdViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  webView = [CDVViewController new];
  webView.startPage = @"MYWEBSITE";   
    [self addChildViewController:webView];
    [self.webView addSubview:webView.view];

    webView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    [activityind startAnimating];
    [self.webView addSubview: activityind];
    [self CustomActivity];
}


-(void) CustomActivity
{
    if ([webView.reference isEqualToString:@"TRUE"]){   //webView.reference is something I added into phonegap CDVViewController so that I am able to see when it is being loaded/used to load the custom activity/activity ind to work.
       [activityind removeFromSuperview];
    }else{
       [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.5 target:self selector:@selector(CustomActivity) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    }
}

- (IBAction)Refresh:(id)sender {

    webView = [CDVViewController new];              
    webView.startPage = @"MYWEBSITE"; 

    [self addChildViewController:webView];
    [self.webView addSubview:webView.view];


    webView.view.frame = CGRectMake (0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,(self.view.frame.size.height -44));
    [activityind startAnimating];
    [self.webView addSubview: activityind];
    [self CustomActivity];
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {}
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)subview {}
- (void)loading {}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning{[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, I had to implement [webView.webView reload];

```
- (IBAction)Refresh:(id)sender {

[webView.webView reload];

}
```